# How to stop video playing in VideoView programmatically in android?

Tags: android, controls, android-videoview

I am using VideoView for playing video,I would like to stop the playing video completely.Please help me on this for solving it.Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

using this code u can stop videoplayer

```
videoView.stopPlayback();
```

For further [ref link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
 videoView.stopPlayback();
 videoView.resume();
```

Answer (score 0):

First **Check your video is available or not** then stop this video.It's better for you

> ```
> if(null!=videoView){ 
> videoView.stopPlayback();  
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> usually used when onBackPressed method like this

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() { 
        if (videoView!=null) 
            videoView.stopPlayback(); 
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
```