# how resume playback after stopPlayback? (Android)

Tags: android

Continue this topic:

[How to stop video playing in VideoView programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9662390/how-to-stop-video-playing-in-videoview-programmatically-in-android)

how resume playback after stopPlayback?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To stop video

```
 // will stop and release the media player instance and move to idle state
 videoView.stopPlayback()
```

To start new play

```
// fist set video path
videoView.setVideoPath("path"); // will release the previous media player instance if any
videoView.start() // will start if not in prepare/error state
```

To pause the current playing

```
// pause the video
videoView.pause()  // will pause if already playing
```

Resume the video from current pause position

```
// resume the video
videoView.resume()  // will resume from the last paused state
```

Comment: i m trying to do same have followed your code but unfortunately it starts playing video from first position instead of seekTo position

Comment: thanks man, you are doing a better job than google. this stopPlayback() has no documentation at this place http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#stopPlayback(), at this time. I was looking at ways of releasing the player.

Answer (score -1):

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

mediaPlayer.pause();
length=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

mediaPlayer.seekTo(length);
mediaPlayer.start();